# Adding Google map API within the Angular 2 form

Tags: angular, forms, google-maps, angular2-forms

I need to get the address from the Google map and wants to parse that address to the form.

This is the code how I integrated the map in angular 2

> **register.component.ts**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapOptions);

    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: "Hello World!"
    });
  }
```

> **register.component.html**

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

> **index.html**

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[api_key]"></script>
```

Here I just integrated the map only.

I want the map with the property that **if I drag the marker it needs to get and parse the json address of where I left the marker**.

```
address={
    country:"",
    state:"",
    pincode:"",
    city:"",
    street:""
    }
```

I want the final address like this.
can anyone please help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing missing in your code is the event listener for the marker to me dragged.

First add this after the title when you are creating the marker:

```
position: myLatlng,
map: map,
title: "Hello World!",
draggable: true
```

Then the Listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {

// Here goes the code thats going to execute after you finish dragging the marker

});
```

now what you want to do after you finish dragging the marker is to do a reverse geocode with the lat and lng of the marker, and you need to go through the response, to get the info you want.

about reverse geocoding: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding

about how to implement geocode API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

about the reverse geocoding response:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#reverse-example

As you can see in the response you have "types"  that tells you the type of address like street or postal code, and in the "long_name" the actual value for that type.

Is not that hard just need to do a bit of homework.